# How to insert div class into JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am trying to write the bootstrap panel head and body in JQuery.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" id="panel_title">Demo</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                <div id=print_received_table></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

If it is one div element we can create like this 
`document.createElement('div')` but what about if it is more than one div.

This class `<div class="panel panel-default">`
i would like to make the parent node.

I am stuck here only. please suggest me how to do?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to create it using `jquery` or `javascript`?

Comment: @guruprasad JQuery..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it as below:

```
var element=$('<div class="panel panel-default">'
              +'<div class="panel-heading">'
              +'<h3 class="panel-title" id="panel_title">Demo</h3>'
              +'</div>'
              +'<div class="panel-body">'
              +'<div id="print_received_table"></div>'
              +'</div>'
              +'</div>'
            );
```

Now you can use the `element` and append it anywhere in the `DOM` as below:

```
$('yourselectorID').append(element);
```

Other option would be creating `element` one by one and then appending it according to its structure finally appending it to `DOM` as below:

```
var parent=$('<div/>', {
    class: 'panel panel-default',
});

var heading=$('<div/>', {
    class: 'panel-heading',
});

var h3=$('<h3/>', {
    class: 'panel-title',
    id:'panel_title',
    text:'Demo'
});

var body=$('<div/>', {
    class: 'panel-body',
});

var prTable=$('<div/>', {
    id: 'print_received_table',
});

heading.append(h3);
body.append(prTable);
var element=parent.append(heading).append(body);
```

Now you have your `element` which can be appended to `DOM`  using same `.append` method mentioned previously. But as of my opinion this feels fishy and difficult to read, and this is just one more way to do it.

---

**UPDATE**

The method your are asking me to show is using pure javascript and you can use `appendChild` and `className` etc as below:

```
var parent = document.createElement("div");
parent.className="panel panel-default";

var heading = document.createElement("div");
heading.className="panel-heading";
var h3=document.createElement("h3");
h3.className="panel-title";
h3.setAttribute('id','panel_title');
var t = document.createTextNode("DEMO"); 
h3.appendChild(t);
heading.appendChild(h3);

var pbody=document.createElement('div');
pbody.className="panel-body";
var prTable=document.createElement('div');
prTable.setAttribute('id','print_received_table');
pbody.appendChild(prTable);

parent.appendChild(heading);
parent.appendChild(pbody);
```

Now you can use `parent element` to `append` it anywhere in `DOM` using `appendChild`

Comment: ` document.createElement('div') ` can we do with this?

Comment: we can do.. you need to use `.appendChild` then to append inner contents. @Awanti

Comment: Can u show me one example?? if it is more than one div??

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Pass the full html string to the constructor like this:

```js
var element = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title" id="panel_title">Demo</h3></div><div class="panel-body"><div id=print_received_table></div></div></div>';


$('#result').append(element);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"><?div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches to do so, and while you can do it in one shot and let DOM parse that fragment itself (see Guruprasad or Delighted answers) you also can chain jquery commands like this:

```
 $('<div />').addClass('panel panel-default')
      .append('<div />').addClass('panel-heading')
         .append('<h3 />').addClass('panel-title').text('Demo')
         .end().end()
      .append('<div />').addClass('panel-body')
         .append('<div />').attr('id', 'print_received_table')
```